# Why does PostgreSQL allow frame clause without order by expression?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, you can specify frame clause without order by clause. The following works:

```
create table dual (dummy character varying);
insert into dual values ('X');

select min(dummy) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                        UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
from dual;
select min(dummy) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 10 FOLLOWING) 
from dual;
```

In Oracle, you cannot do this (you will get "missing ORDER by expression in the window specification"). This makes sense to me - rows are not ordered and it makes no sense to ask for preceding and following rows.

When reading the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) `[frame_clause]` is optional and independent from `[ORDER by expression]`, but I do not see why this would be needed/useful.

Why does PostgreSQL allow this behavior?

Comment: The answer is probably hidden somewhere in the pgsql-hackers archive, in a lengthy discussion about the windowing function implementation. But why don't just add the ORDER BY and both databases are happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A window clause is part of the SELECT phase, and in that phase of query processing there actually is a row order.  If you don't specify an `order by`, it'll just be a random order.

One thing you can do with that is include a column from the next row as a convenience, for example:

```
select  id
,       max(id) over (rows between 1 following and 1 following) as next_id
from    AnyTable
```

A client that reads rows in sequential order, but needs the id of the next row for some reason, could make use of this.